# To Automate Continuous Data Copying from MongoDB to S3

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, triggers

While Creating a MongoDB Atlas Trigger to Copy New MongoDB Data into S3 i face the following error:
(InternalError) an error occurred when communicating with AWS S3, correlationID = 171b627ff3bf958f2718893a

could anyone help me solving this issue